# An HTTP cache that will fall back to last successful response on failures

Tags: nginx, http, cache, squid

Is there an HTTP caching layer that I could use in front of my website that can be configured to fall back to return the last successful response (200 - 399 status) from the cache, if it encounters a bad response (>=400 status) at the same URL? Similar to [Cloudflare's "Always online" feature](https://www.cloudflare.com/always-online/).

I've been trying to see if Squid or Nginx caches can be configured to do this, but I haven't found anything clear so far.

Comment: Varnish has that feature.

Comment: nginx can certainly do that, e.g. with `proxy_cache_use_stale`.